# Sort results returned from a query, like a nested query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a query, that I use to find the latest rankings of keyword a huge table. I use the following query to achieve that.

```
@results = KeywordRanking.includes(:business_keyword, :keyword)
                           .where("business_keyword_id in (?)",
                                  biz_keywords.select(:id))
                           .select("distinct on (business_keyword_id) *")
                           .order("business_keyword_id, rank_date desc")
```

Initially we used to do pagination on the frontend, but lately we shifted to will_paginate and required to sort it in the backend. But when I pass in another order query. It gets appended to the existing query which makes the system not only sort with respect to `rank_date` but also a second field called rank.

I presently I pass in the second order like bellow

```
@result = if params[:sort]
  @result.order("#{params[:sort]} desc")
end
```

While writing raw query, we just build a nested query where we sort the results we get. How do we do that in rails.

Comment: How are you passing another order query ? I mean the the code when you are passing another order query.

Comment: @sajan I have updated that in my question.

Comment: well, you are getting the expected behavior as you are doing another sorting on the previously sorted data which is stored in `@result` . There are many ways to avoid that, I will be able suggest one after I understand your need like when do you data to be sorted by `rank_date desc` and when you are sorting by column in params ?

Comment: I know its doing the expected behaviour. But my question is how do we sort the results of this query. The above query would give me 1000 results (based on the number of keywords I have), and I want to sort that 1000 row. I can do that in SQL using nested queries. I want to do the same in rails.

Comment: Note that using `params[:sort]` directly is dangerous as users might send malicious input in it. Use a whitelist instead. See http://rails-sqli.org/#order